# You uploaded a file that is not a well formed zip archive

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

When I try to release an aab, I am getting this error. Someone help me please. How can I fix it.
See the image by clicking the blue link
[image: error image]

Comment: You have to give us more info si we can help you, e.g. what have you tried? How did you build it? If you rename the extension of the AAB to .zip, can you open it?

Comment: Thanks for reply @Pierre Yes I have generated the signed aab using android studio by following the correct way. I also tried renaming True Id aab.aab  to TrueID.aab but the problem still persists.

Comment: What about my second question: have you tried renaming the extension of the file to .zip and extract it as a normal zip file?

Comment: Try with removing old apk from folder or try with clean and rebuilt

Comment: Did you found solution for this issue? @FaribaLaiq

Comment: Yes @Vishal Pawar solution worked.

Answer (score 10):

I kept regularly getting this error when using drag & drop to the web browser.
The issue didn't occur if I used the "Upload" button on the page and selecting the AAB using a file chooser.

One may want to try this approach before rebuilding, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue, I solved by doing this

```
clean you project
rebuild project
create new build (.aab file, make sure increase build number)
now upload this new file then error has resolved
```

this worked for me.